# Desktop is black, not visible (Lubuntu 20)

Tags: lubuntu, icons

Am using Lubuntu running on modern Computer (i5), new installation of v20. (german)

Files on Desktop are visible in the pcfm-filemanager, but the desktop itself is black.

KLicking on "Desktop Options" says, that the Desktop Administration is not acitve.

Always when I want to shut the PC down, the question comes: Herunterfahren der LXQT-Sitzung: Möchten Sie wirklich herunterfahren, alle ungespeicherten Arbeiten gehen verloren". (shut down of lxqt-session: do you really want, all unsaved stuff gets lost) Why???

Recently, the internet-connection broke, and then I suddenly had desktop. After restart again black...

Anyone has help?

eddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get a terminal type

```
lxqt-config
```

Then select the desktop and see how you go. Then if you reboot it should come back.

As for the lxqt-session, if you get your desktop back, close this question and ask a new question with just those details. Viel Glück

Comment: After typing this it says: 
((nil)) Warning: QFileSystemWatcher::removePaths: list is empty; and then opens window Configuration Center

Comment: In that case it looks like it has "gone away" so type `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

Comment: Yes, it's there! Thanx!

Comment: Good to hear, please accept this answer (icon on the LHS) so your question shows as such.